# How to Connect the database from Testing(QA) server into SSMS(SQL Server 2017)?

Tags: c#, asp.net, coldfusion

We have a previously created a project in Coldfusion -- it is slow in bringing the data back from the server, so the team has decided to convert from Coldfusion API's to Entity Framework.Net Core API's.

Visual studio is failing to connect to QA(Testing)Server, so my API's do not work.

Now, I am trying to connect the database from QA Server -- database gets open only in visual studio 2017, and I am unable to open in SQL Server(SSMS) due to permission issue.

In order to open the same database of QA Server into SSMS(SQL Server 2017), what should I do?

I want my API's to connect with the server and bring the data back.
Does anyone go through such an issue before? Any Help will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you write exactly what error did you get?

Comment: One thing this tells me is that the problem isn't with ColdFusion having issues connecting to the database. There's a  problem with the connection to the database itself. I would also mention that I have personally seen an attempt at converting a ColdFusion code base to a ,Net framework. The 9 months that it was supposed to take still wasn't done when I left a few years later.

Comment: All that said, what does your query look like? What are the permissions of the users in SQL Server? You very well might be trying to connect to your database with a user that doesn't have permissions to do so.

Comment: "it is slow in bringing the data back from the server" > Can you run the raw queries in SQL Manager and how long does that take to run? Could be entirely an issue with the query, missing indexes, poor database architecture, DB server resources or other things not related to the CF server. Have you ruled those out before trying to implement this other process which seems to be having issues of its own?